# Is the set of all partial function from N to {1} are enumerable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set of all partial functions from N to {1} are not enumerable. Can anyone give me a hint how to show this using Cantor's diagonalization argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This set is actually exactly the same as the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0, 1\}$.

Consider the mapping $f \mapsto \tilde{f}$  where we say $\tilde{f}(x) = 1$ wherever $f$ is defined, and $\tilde{f}(x) = 0$ wherever it is not. It is trivial to see that this is a bijection.

Then the usual diagonalisation argument works.

Comment: ... which can obviously map to the binary representation of real numbers in [0,1], nice.

Comment: Thanks Michael! what a perfect and brief explanation!!! How about if it is a total function from N to {1}?

Comment: Thanks, glad to be of help. There is exactly one total function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1\}$, the constant function.

Comment: Oh!! I didn't thought about that .... many thanks again!!!

Answer (score 3):

Such a function is determined by the set of points where it is defined, so your set of partial functions is in bijective correspondence with $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: I didn't understand you answer! Can you give me some details

Comment: @Myke: All there is to know about a partial function $\mathbb N\to \{1\}$ is the set of numbers it is defined for. So every subset of $\mathbb N$ corresponds to exactly one such function and vice versa. You know how to prove that the set of subsets of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable, right?